# "I'm running late for 5 minutes." Or "I'm running late."

Tags: phrases, idioms, time

When using the idiomatic phrase "running late", can you add time afterwards? e.g. "I'm runnng late for 5min."

Or is it fixed as just "running late."?

Comment: I am  5 minutes late.

Comment: Or *I am running 5 minutes late*

Comment: Or *I am late **by** 5 minutes.*

Answer (score 4):

In American English, the idiomatic wording of your sentence when including the time is:

> I'm running 5 minutes late.

Note that most style guides suggest spelling out numbers less than ten, thus:

> I'm running five minutes late.